# @font-face giving ultra-heavy font weight and/or bad anti-aliasing

Tags: css, font-face, antialiasing

I found an open font I liked ([Crete Round](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/crete-round)) and designed some screens in Photoshop with it.  When it came time to set up the CSS, I tried using both Google Fonts and fontsquirrel.com's downloadable "kit" (a zip file with four different types of fonts and a ready-made stylesheet), but both gave me strange results on Mac.

**Photoshop** — What I want it to look like:

[image]

**Yuck** — Chrome (and Safari) on Mac using an @font-face kit from fontsquirrel.com:

[image]

Chrome (and Safari) on Mac using Google Fonts (basically identical):

[image]

**GOOD** —Chrome on Windows (fontsquirrel):

[image]

**GOOD** — Hack. I found out that with any opacity (*not* text color alpha) less than 1.0, Chrome gave me good results (but Safari was still bad.)

Chrome on Mac using fontsquirrel, with `opacity:0.999;`:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on here, or what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: The worst I find it the character "i" only renders properly for most fonts at particular sizes (fills the gap between the dot and the line so it looks like "l").

Comment: Just curious if font-smooth:always helps.

Comment: @AshwinSingh it appears that font-smooth always doesn't change anything.

Comment: What is going on is that you don't seem to have realized that Adobe and all those browsers are entirely separate applications. They do not and need not render things identically. That said, you can use text-shadow to trick the eye into seeing various weights and antialiasing approaches that aren't truly so.

Comment: @resio No need for insulting sarcasm.  I just wanted to realize the design in the final medium the way I had envisioned it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. I also don't think there is a way around it, other than to use images instead of text where the style is absolutely crucial.

I found [THIS LINK](http://blog.typekit.com/2010/10/21/type-rendering-web-browsers/) which discusses rendering engines on different operating systems (also taking different browsers into consideration).

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

try

`html { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }`

Comment: Could also add *, html, body { -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; } to affect all elements. [Explained more here](http://maxvoltar.com/archive/-webkit-font-smoothing)